# MySQL Query to select free slots from appointments

Tags: mysql

I try to select the free hours from my appointment system.
table1:

```
table1: working hours

worker   starthour  endhour
---------------------------
1        10:00      18:00

table2: appointments

app   starthour  endhour
---------------------------
1        10:30      11:00
2        12:00      12:40
```

So, I need to display something like this:

```
available hours

starthour  endhour
------------------
10:00      10:30
11:00      12:00
12:40      18:00
```

Any help would be appreciated!

This is my code but I am not sure it is the best idea:

```
select x.eh, min(y.sh)

from 
(
select '18:00' as sh, '10:00' as eh from dual
union
select '10:30' as sh, '11:00' as eh from dual union
select '12:00' as sh, '13:00' as eh from dual
) x,
(
select '18:00' as sh, '10:00' as eh from dual
union
select '10:30' as sh, '11:00' as eh from dual union
select '12:00' as sh, '13:00' as eh from dual
) y
where x.eh <> x.sh
and     y.sh > x.eh
group by x.eh
order by x.eh
```

Comment: If you created a third table to store working hour increments with the columns starthour and endhour then store a record for each 5-minute increments (or whatever you thought was best) you could probably get pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This is an answer:

```
select freestart, freeend from (
select 
    max(x.eh) as freestart, y.sh as freeend   
from (
select '18:00' as sh, '10:00' as eh from dual
union
select '10:00' as sh, '10:30' as eh from dual
union
select '12:00' as sh, '12:40' as eh from dual
union
select '15:00' as sh, '15:20' as eh from dual
) x,
(
select '18:00' as sh, '10:00' as eh from dual
union
select '10:00' as sh, '10:30' as eh from dual
union
select '12:00' as sh, '12:40' as eh from dual
union
select '15:00' as sh, '15:20' as eh from dual
) y
where x.eh <> y.sh
and     y.sh > x.eh
and x.eh <> y.eh
group by y.sh
order by x.eh
) z
order by z.freestart
```